# A collective idea - noun pharse

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, semantics

" The concerns that the teachers have risen is an indicator for having training the soonest .

My question here is , can I use the singular verb "is" with the main plural  subject "concerns" , bearing in mind that I mean all the concerns work as a unit to be an indicator.

Comment: Just because ***the concerns*** are plural doesn't prevent them being linked to singular ***indicator*** (using the plural copula verb form ***are***). See [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+are+an+indicator&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) for *which **are** an indicator*.

Answer (score 0):

No - 'the concerns' is a plural noun, so you should use 'are'. What follows your plural noun is a defining clause, it doesn't form a noun phrase.

To make this into a singular noun phrase you need to make the verb - the act of *rising* concerns - the main part of the noun phrase:

For example:

> *Teachers raising concerns* is an indicator we should have training soon.

Or you could introduce another singular noun, for example:

> *The fact* that teachers have raised concerns is an indicator we should train soon.

Comment: Surely it should be '**raised** concerns'?

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, it has a direct object so it should be 'raised'. Hopefully the OP will pick up on that as it isn't part of their question

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. "The concerns" is plural and so requires a plural verb. Sure, "the concerns" are acting together. But in any sentence that uses a plural, the things making up the subject are acting together in some sense. If there's just one verb, then the plural subject must all be doing that one thing.

Note: There are a couple of other problems with your sentence. 1. You should say, "the concerns that the teachers have raised", not "have risen". "Risen" means that the thing rose itself. The concerns didn't raise themselves nor did the teachers rise. The teachers raised concerns. You could say, "The concerns that have risen ..."

2. You should say "for having training sooner" or "for having training as soon as possible". "Soonest" is an adjective, a word that modifies a noun. The sentence calls for a word to modify "having", which is a verb, and so you need an adverb, a word that modifies a verb. This is, perhaps, confusing because "sooner" can also be an adjective. You can say, "this even is sooner" or "this event is the soonest". You can say "we will do this sooner". But you CAN'T say "we will do this soonest".

So a correct sentence would be, "The concerns that the teachers have raised are an indicator for having training sooner", or "The concerns that have arisen are an indicator for having training as soon as possible."